# Concatenate or TextJoin Same Cell Multiple Times based on Value in another Cell?

Tags: excel, string, concatenation

I'm struggling with a problem in Excel right now with some Amino Acid data.

The idea is that i would have a string of AA residues that need to be polymerized (functionally contatenated to themselves) a number of times based on a multiplier.

So, if I have a sequence AAGKLY, and I want to polymerize it 4 times, I should end up with AAGKLYAAGKLYAAGKLYAAGKLY.

Ideally, AAGKLY would be in a cell, the number 4 would be in a cell next to it, and my formula would spit out the full concatenation in the final cell.

Concatenate() seems to be my best bet, but I can't use VBA to do any sort of While Loop.  My other option seems to be a massive if statement, but then I have to worry about someone using this sheet to do something like a 50 times polymerization while I've only written up to 40 if statements.  Is there a good way to leverage the concatenate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the [`REPT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rept-function-04c4d778-e712-43b4-9c15-d656582bb061) function is what you are looking for:

```
=REPT("ABC",4) => ABCABCABCABC
```

Comment: I'm sad because I somehow totally missed this.  Thank you!

Comment: Don't beat yourself up: if I wouldn't have used this some time ago, I would not have thought about it either :-)